# Adding android:required="false" doesn't remove from Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, uses-feature

I am developing an app for Android and after uploading it to Google Play, In the features menu it shows that i am using android.hardware.camera.autofocus [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MqEb.png) while in my Manifest I already set it to android:required="false" [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIKJw.png) My Question is that how is this possible when i already set it to false? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `android:required` attribute is meaningless for this device feature. It is used for other features such as AR or VR where additional libraries can be downloaded if needed.

In other words, setting this attribute to false does not make your app compatible with devices that don't have this feature. Either you set the whole device feature tag (and it's required) it or you don't (and it's not required).